# PostgreSQL: Getting average value for rows matching a column

Tags: postgresql

I am experimenting with the following query to get rows based on a time. When I get the rows, I want to average the values in a column, and return one row with the average value as JSON. Hopefully it'll make sense with some code. Here's the PostgreSQL query I'm starting with:

```
select row_to_json(row)
  from (
    SELECT "responses"."index", "responses"."created_at",
    ROUND(AVG("responses"."value")) AS value
    FROM "responses"
    WHERE "responses"."time" = '1416177080'
    GROUP BY "responses"."index", "responses"."created_at"
  ) row
```

That produces output like:

```
{"index":4,"created_at":"2014-11-16 22:31:27","value":5}
{"index":4,"created_at":"2014-11-16 22:31:23","value":-5}
{"index":4,"created_at":"2014-11-16 22:31:24","value":0}
{"index":4,"created_at":"2014-11-16 22:31:25","value":-1}
{"index":4,"created_at":"2014-11-16 22:31:26","value":1}
(5 rows)
```

When what I really want is just one row with the average as the value. Like this:

```
{"index_of_affiliation":4,"created_at":"2014-11-16 22:31:27","value":0}
```

I feel like the `created_at` might throw me off but I'd like to return a value for that in the JSON. Any feedback as to how I can get my desired one row with an averaged value would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines might work.

```
select row_to_json(row)
from (select "index" index_of_affiliation, 
             max("created_at") max_created_at, 
             round(avg("value")) avg_value
      from responses
      where "time" = '1416177080'
      group by "index"
     ) row ;
```

In the long run, you're better off with more descriptive names than "index", "value", and "time".